# Golang call by reference

Tags: go

I want to understand golang call by reference.I wrote this piece of code. When I print both the address(1st address in main and 2nd address in printPointer, it looks different).Please help to understand better.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type person struct{
 name string
 id string
}

func main() {
//struct
 c := person{name: "vijay", id: "1234",}
 fmt.Println(&c)
 printPointer(&c)
 fmt.Println(c)

}

func printPointer(p *person) {
 (*p).name = "Sree"
fmt.Println(&p)
}
```

Comment: Go does not have call-by-reference. Go has call-by-value, with the option of passing a reference *as* the value, either explicitly (as you are doing) or implicitly (method calls that require a pointer to the method instance). With an implicit pointer, there's relatively little difference, but the explicit pointer style is what makes this call-by-value in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `printPointer`, you're printing the value `&p`, or "pointer to p". p is of type `*person`, or "pointer to person". Thus, the value you're actually printing is of type "pointer to pointer to person" which I don't think is your intention.

Try printing just `p`.

Answer (score 4):

In go, all arguments are passed by value. Thus:

```
fmt.Println(c)
```

This receives a copy of `c`

```
fmt.Println(&c)
```

This received a copy of `&c`.

In your code, `printPointer` receives a copy of `&c` as `p`. When you print `&p`, you print the address of that copy, not `&c`.

Use `fmt.Println(p)`.